# Which Meta Query Compare Method Should I use?

Tags: meta-query

How do I do a 'like' comparison on a numeric value with meta_query?

I have some code that does an autocomplete search for product sku's in WooCommmerce. It works fine for non numeric skus, but I can't get it working with numeric skus. I'm using compare => 'like' because my autocomplete script is setup to start searching after 2 characters have been entered (so that skus 10 characters long can be searched instead of entered exactly). Here's what I'm working with now:

```
$products1 = array(
    'post_type' => array ('product', 'product_variation'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => '_sku',
        'value' => $_REQUEST['term'],
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
    'fields' => 'ids'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason that the meta query should not work. The database column is `varchar` so your number is going to be treated as a string. I tested as best I can without having your database and the testing seems to confirm that.

I think you are going to get a lot of spurious matches. The default `LIKE` search will put a `%` wildcard at each end of the string so that `123` will match anywhere in the string, for example, here-- `12345678`-- but also here-- `45678123`. I suspect that you only want a one sided `LIKE` so that `123` matches but at the front of `12345123` but not the end. You need a filter for that.

```
function one_sided_like($sql) {
  remove_filter('get_meta_sql','wildcard_meta_like');
  $pat = '%([^%]*)%';
  preg_match('|'.$pat.'|',$sql['where'],$matches);
  if (!empty($matches[1])) {
    $sql['where'] = str_replace($matches[0],$matches[1].'%',$sql['where']);
  }
  return $sql;
}
add_filter('get_meta_sql','one_sided_like');
```